# Like button on external website missing counts when not logged into Facebook

Tags: facebook-like, external

Two days ago, I started having a problem with the like button on my external website. If I view the website while I am logged into Facebook, then the like button is OK. However, if I view the page while I am not logged into Facebook, then the number of likes displayed on the page is only a tiny fraction of what it should be. This problem occurs on other websites as well, and it occurs with all web browsers. I have the "app_id" and all other parameters installed correctly, as none of this information has changed. This is probably related to the like button migration. I know the problem above can be fixed by migrating the administration page and changing the url for the like button to the url of the migrated administration page, as I was able to do so on one of my other pages. However, I prefer not to migrate the administration page for this particular external website. Is there a way to fix this problem without migrating the administration page? Thanks.